# Google map that plot's several markers - each one with custom data

Tags: custom-field, google-maps

I'm looking to create a custom Google map that plots several markers on it that then shows custom data in the popup when the marker is clicked.

I've setup the pages in WP in this manner:

Map (parent page)

- Company one (child)
- Company two (child)
- Company three (child)

...and so on.

I want the map to be on the map page and each marker to be of the child pages.

I use [this plugin](http://plugins.elliotcondon.com/advanced-custom-fields/) to create custom fields as it allows me to easily create the 20 or so fields (each one consists of various checkboxes, drop downs, image fields etc etc) per page.

**How would I loop through each child page and plot the marker based on their post code?**

Comment: Take a look at the get_children function. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children

Comment: @BrianFegter It's plotting the markers more than anything thats the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done something similar using gmaps (http://gmap.nurtext.de/). You might want to take a look at that. It's self explanatory and there's quite a bit of documentation IF you google around.

Answer (score 0):

[Mappress](http://wphostreviews.com/product/mappress) is a really good solution for adding maps to posts and pages in WordPress.